# Solving for an angle using trigonometry.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Trying again
[image]

$\dfrac{\sin(180 - \theta - a)}{H + R} = \dfrac{\sin(a)}{R}$

$\dfrac{\sin(\theta + a)}{ H + R} = \dfrac{\sin (a) }{ R}$  (is this correct?)

${\sin(\theta + a)} = \dfrac{{ H + R}}{ R}\sin (a) $

${(\theta + a)} = arcsin(\dfrac{{ H + R}}{ R}\sin (a))$

${\theta} = arcsin(\dfrac{{ H + R}}{ R}\sin (a)) - a$

allows me to get the arc x = ${\theta} * R$

[image]

Comment: $\cos \theta = R/(R+H)$

Comment: It's a bit confusing why you have an arc there. Is the exterior line supposed to be tangent to the circle? That's necessary for @user3001408's comment to be true. Is this triangle a right triangle?

Comment: What I'm trying to get to eventually is the length of the arc as a diminishes. If I'm not mistaken my arc is 2 * Theta (in rad). So I want to get theta in terms of a so I can calculate how my arc shrinks as a gets smaller (see second diagram)

Comment: at the max size of the arcx, that line would be a tangent to the circle

Answer (score 0):

from your last one:

$\sin{(\theta+a)}=\sin{\theta}\cos{a}+\cos{\theta}\cos{a}=x\cos{a}+\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos{a}$

$x=\sin{\theta}$

$x\cos{a}+\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos{a}=\dfrac{{ H + R}}{ R}\sin (a)$

solve $x$ ,you can get $\sin{\theta}$.(I suppose $a$ is known.)

Comment: found the way through, see above

Comment: @NeedingHelp,you have to be very careful to $\theta +a$, is it less than $ \frac{\pi}{2}$ ?